# Arduino and Plotly

Tags: upload, arduino-uno, plotly

I want to send multiple sensor data to plotly using node.js. I have some code for sending multiple streams, but in the command prompt when it shows the msg all the streams are ready to go. It is sending first sensor data with timestamp on x axis and the value on y-axis, but for the second sensor it is only sending the timestamp(x-axis value) but not the value of the sensor. So can anyone tell where am i making a mistake? The code for arduino screenshot attached.
[arduino code part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNJ4G.png)
[commandprompt output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIfRa.png)

[arduino code part2][3]

```
var serialport = require('serialport'),
plotly = require('plotly')('Maryam_19','vvvvvvvvv');
tokens = ['kfkdfkgrg', 'ggggggg'];


var portName = 'COM3';
var sp = new serialport.SerialPort(portName,{
baudRate: 9600,
dataBits: 8,
parity: 'none',
stopBits: 1,
flowControl: false,
parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\r\n")
});

// helper function to get a nicely formatted date string
function getDateString() {
var time = new Date().getTime();
// 32400000 is (GMT+9 Japan)
// for your timezone just multiply +/-GMT by 3600000
var datestr = new Date(time + 18000000).toISOString().replace(/T/, '      ').replace(/Z/, '');
return datestr;
}
// wanting to create sub-plots with two data-streams
var initdata = [
                {name: 'LeftSensor', x:[], y:[], stream:{token:tokens[0],          maxpoints: 1500}},
                {name: 'RightSensor', x:[], y:[], stream:{token:tokens[1], maxpoints: 1500}}
            ];

var initlayout = {fileopt : 'new', filename : 'Connected Car 1'};

plotly.plot(initdata, initlayout, function (err, msg) {
if (err) return console.log(err)

console.log(msg);

// creating two streams
var streams = {
    'LeftSensor' : plotly.stream(tokens[0], function (err, res) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log(err, res);
    }),
    'RightSensor' : plotly.stream(tokens[1], function (err, res) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log(err, res);
    })
};
sp.on('data', function(input) {


    if(isNaN(input) || input > 1023) return;

    var values = input.split('\t');

    // writing the leftSensor stream
    var leftStreamObject = JSON.stringify({ x : getDateString(), y :   values[0] });
    console.log('LeftSensorObject: ' + leftStreamObject);
    streams['LeftSensor'].write(leftStreamObject + '\n');

       // writing the rightsensor stream
    var RightStreamObject = JSON.stringify({ x : getDateString(), y :    values[1] });
    console.log('RightSensorObject: ' + RightStreamObject);
    streams['RightSensor'].write(RightSensorObject + '\n');
});
```

});

Comment: The reading for the second sensor is also being send actually but with the first sensor..like firstly it send the left sensor reading , then the right sensor reading but in left sensor tag

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you **edit** your post and add an example of trace in your serial monitor? Moreover, it is hard to understand what is what in this question: the variables in your sketch are not named *first sensor* or *second sensor*, could you edit your description of the problem to fix this? Last: could you pin-point what line of code doesn't produce the desired output?

Comment: the variable 'distance' is showing the distance of left sensor and the variable 'distance1' is showing the distance of right sensor. and code is working fine on serial monitor. but when i open the command prompt and run my plotly code to send it, it is sending the data of both the sensors but not diffrentiating..i mean to say that it is sending the value of the right sensor as also the left sensor value. Because i can see only one line in my graph telling both the reading. whereas i should have two seperate line showing the seperate readings.

Comment: how do you connect **plotly** to the Arduino data? does it read directly through serial? what is the data that is read by the app? can you **edit** your question and add relevant **input/output** so that we can **reproduce** the issue and thus help you?

Comment: i want to add screenshots and my plotly code..but i cant add more images , it says i have to earn more badges..so what should i do to add screeshots?

Comment: just don't add screenshots.. you can simply add the code as text, just be sure to add 4 spaces on the left of every line, to properly indent it. :)

Comment: see my plotly code now

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
sp.on('data', function(input) {
    if(isNaN(input) || input > 1023) return;

    var values = input.split('\t');

    var leftStreamObject = JSON.stringify({ x : getDateString(), y :   values[0] });
    console.log('LeftSensorObject: ' + leftStreamObject);
    streams['LeftSensor'].write(leftStreamObject + '\n');

    var RightStreamObject = JSON.stringify({ x : getDateString(), y :    values[1] });
    console.log('RightSensorObject: ' + RightStreamObject);
    streams['RightSensor'].write(RightSensorObject + '\n');
});
```

you assume that `input`, which I guess here it's supposed to be a **line**, has two values separated by a **tab** symbol.

However, that isn't what you print in your **Arduino Code**.

I suggest you change the latter's source code like this:

```
void loop () {
    ...
    distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;
    Serial.print(distance);
    Serial.print('\t');
    delay(2000);
    ...
    distance1 = (duration1/2) / 29.1;
    Serial.println(distance1);
    delay(2000);
 }
```

This should make the output of the Arduino device compatible with your parser.

---

On a separate note, I would like to suggest that perhaps declaring distance to be an **int** is not correct, unless you're aware of the fact that dividing an integer by a float (*29.1*) and then storing the result in an integer results in an approximation error.

If that's not the case, you should:

- declare distance and distance1 to be *float*
- divide distance and distance1 by *2.0* instead of *2*

---

**EDIT**:

To solve the second issue you are experiencing, I suggest you modify your **python** code like this:

```
sp.on('data', function(input) {
    input = input.strip()

    if not len(input) > 0:
        return

    var values = input.split('\t');

    if len(values) != 2:
        raise ValueError('Unable to parse <' + str + '> input.')

    var leftStreamObject = JSON.stringify({ x : getDateString(), y :   values[0] });
    console.log('LeftSensorObject: ' + leftStreamObject);
    streams['LeftSensor'].write(leftStreamObject + '\n');

    var RightStreamObject = JSON.stringify({ x : getDateString(), y :    values[1] });
    console.log('RightSensorObject: ' + RightStreamObject);
    streams['RightSensor'].write(RightSensorObject + '\n');
});
```

Comment: yes it works by adding the tab in the arduino code..but now it is sending the data as shown in the screenshot..sending two reading and then two blank readings..

Comment: it gives an error of unexpected identifier..on this line:
 if not len(input) > 0:

Comment: well its ok , atleast i am able to get both of the readings on plotly. thankyou

Comment: ok..but not working on mine. I also want to send 2 more sensor readings. Have done it in the same way but now it's only sending one reading, the others reading blank only the timestamp

Comment: You should try to learn how to code and do some practice, I don't see what's on your machine so I can't help you any further than this. Cheers! :)

Comment: can u just tell me last time that if i want to send more sensors data i just have to add the tab after every sensor data and make some additions in the plotly code like to add another token and stream?

Comment: You should check that everything you send is on the same line and separated by tabs, yes. And you should appropriately change the parse function to check for 4 arguments and ignore anything less than that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var serialport = require('serialport'),
 plotly = require('plotly')('Maryam_19','xoius1zote');
 tokens = ['fqar271jly', '1vnlkdlt7l','x3lfitv9qb','4qvzyuq050'];


 var portName = 'COM7';
 var sp = new serialport.SerialPort(portName,{
 baudRate: 9600,
 dataBits: 8,
 parity: 'none',
 stopBits: 1,
 flowControl: false,
 parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\r\n")
 });

// helper function to get a nicely formatted date string
function getDateString() {
var time = new Date().getTime();
// 32400000 is (GMT+9 Japan)
// for your timezone just multiply +/-GMT by 3600000
var datestr = new Date(time + 18000000).toISOString().replace(/T/, '               ').replace(/Z/, '');
return datestr;
}
```

// wanting to create sub-plots with two data-streams
     var initdata = [
                {name: 'LeftSensor', x:[], y:[], stream:{token:tokens[0],           maxpoints: 1500}},
                {name: 'RightSensor', x:[], y:[], stream:{token:tokens[1], maxpoints: 1500}},
        {name: 'FrontSensor', x:[], y:[], stream:{token:tokens[2], maxpoints: 1500}},
        {name: 'BackSensor', x:[], y:[], stream:{token:tokens[3], maxpoints: 1500}}
            ];

```
 var initlayout = {fileopt : 'new', filename : 'Connected Car 1'};

 plotly.plot(initdata, initlayout, function (err, msg) {
 if (err) return console.log(err)

 console.log(msg);

 // creating four streams
 var streams = {
 'LeftSensor' : plotly.stream(tokens[0], function (err, res) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(err, res);
    }),
 'RightSensor' : plotly.stream(tokens[1], function (err, res) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(err, res);
    }),

   'FrontSensor' : plotly.stream(tokens[2], function (err, res) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(err, res);
    }),

   'BackSensor' : plotly.stream(tokens[3], function (err, res) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(err, res);
    })

   };
   sp.on('data', function(input) {



  var values = input.split('\t');

// writing the leftSensor stream
   var leftStreamObject = JSON.stringify({ x : getDateString(), y :   values[0] });
 console.log('LeftSensorObject: ' + leftStreamObject);
 streams['LeftSensor'].write(leftStreamObject + '\n');

   // writing the rightsensor stream
   var RightStreamObject = JSON.stringify({ x : getDateString(), y :     values[1] });
 console.log('RightSensorObject: ' + RightStreamObject);
 streams['RightSensor'].write(RightStreamObject + '\n');

 //  writing the frontsensor stream
 var FrontStreamObject = JSON.stringify({ x : getDateString(), y :    values[2] });
  console.log('FrontSensorObject: ' + FrontStreamObject);
  streams['FrontSensor'].write(FrontStreamObject + '\n');

   //writing the Backsensor stream
   var BackStreamObject = JSON.stringify({ x : getDateString(), y :    values[3] });
    console.log('BackSensorObject: ' + BackStreamObject);
    streams['BackSensor'].write(BackStreamObject + '\n');


    });
    });
```